# How to override __setattr__ in a wrapped class (from C++)?

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

Using `boost::python`, I have been able to wrap a class (`Node`) which has some virtual functions, and it's been a hoot, but now I'm trying to override `setattr/getattr` for the class.
I've got `boost::python` to call my own `setattr` implementation, but I can't figure out how to avoid the recursion that happens.

So I have a `Node` class, and I want to be able to write:

```
node1.param1 = 5          # Call node.SetParam
node1.plain_member = 7    # Call object.__setattr__
```

So far, I have (very abridged):

```
namespace bpy = boost::python;

struct NodeWrap : vcNode, bpy::wrapper<Node> {
  ...  
  static void setattr(bpy::object obj, std::string attr, bpy::object val)
  {
     NodeWrap const& node = bpy::extract<NodeWrap const&>(obj)();
     ParamRef p = node.FindParam(attr);
     if (p)
        py_to_param(p, val); //This part works fine
     else
     {
        obj.attr(attr) = val; //Problematic line - recurses indefinitely
     }
  }
};
```

then in the `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` section, I have:

```
bpy::class_<NodeWrap, boost::shared_ptr<NodeWrap>, boost::noncopyable>("Node")
  ...
  .def("__setattr__". &NodeWrap::setattr);
```

As I said, it compiles just fine, and will set any node "params" correctly, but if I try to set a non-param, such as `self.plain_old_member = 7` then I get a "Recursion Depth Exceeded" error, because I gather `boost::object::attr` will call the class' `__setattr__` method

In python, I would get around this by using

```
super(Node).__setattr__(self, attr, val)
```

in the problem line, but I can't figure out how to do that from boost::python.
I don't mind going to the C API if I have to (in fact, I've tried using `PyObject_SetAttrString` to no avail), but I just don't know how to get there from here.

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the Python C-API function you want is `PyObject_GenericSetAttr`; that is, you should replace the "problematic line" with:

```
bpy::str attr_str(attr);
if (PyObject_GenericSetAttr(obj.ptr(), attr_str.ptr(), val.ptr()) != 0)
    bpy::throw_error_already_set();
```

I think this is equivalent to calling `object.__setattr__(self, attr, val)` in Python, which is not the same as calling `__setattr__` on a base class, but the difference only matters if a base class also overrides `__setattr__`.  If that's the case, you'd need to do something like this:

```
bpy::object cls(bpy::handle<>(PyObject_Type(obj.ptr())));
bpy::object base_cls = cls.attr("__bases__")[0];
base_cls.attr("__setattr__")(obj, attr, val);
```

Comment: Great! I had found a slow and ugly workaround (using 'bpy::exec("object.__setattr__(obj, attr, val)"...', which required populating a dict and grabbing __main__.__dict__ every time). Thanks!